# Create a Javascript/html/css Editor App with Intellisense Possible?

Tags: javascript, android

so im currently developing an app that can read javascript/html/css codes and show it inside a webview. So is it possible to have or apply what Android Studio can do on my App? i meant the auto Completion/suggesting for codes (Intellisense or Intellij), and also if possible syntax checker/highlighter? TIA

Comment: Of course it is; you can pretty much write whatever you want.

Comment: any idea on how can i possibly apply that on my app?

Comment: Write code? I mean, writing an editor is non-trivial to begin with; implementing auto-complete and syntax highlighting is even less non-trivial. Take a look at any of a zillion open-source projects that already do this. Personally I'd recommend using a pre-existing component; if you're using a web view then existing implementations may be sufficient--I suspect there's more complexity here than you are aware of yet.

Comment: i see. im just starting to developp my app and already having a hard time understanding most of it.it is more complexed than i though it would be. any Idea where can i possible find or search those kinds of projects? btw Thanks for keeping up with me. really appreciate it

Comment: I'm not sure what your experience level is, but I'd probably start simpler. I'd also investigate what components/libraries/etc. already exist for the target environment; perhaps they could be used as-is, or modified to suit your specific requirements.